# Error: `error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical while  getting a file from a classpath

Tags: java, file, classpath

I have a file contained within a directory in a classpath. It looks like this `pl/shenlon/io/gui/appData/file.txt`. Now, when I try to convert it to a File and read with this code:

```
File cityNamesFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("pl/shenlon/io/gui/appData/list.txt").toURI());
Scanner cns = new Scanner(cityNamesFile);
```

I get the following:-

`error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical.`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried to use File cityNamesFile = new File("classpath:<path_to_file_in_classpath>")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your calling class is itself in the same package as the text file, just use :

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("list.txt");
Scanner cns = new Scanner(is);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But now I'd like to change the encoding of data sent to UTF8. How could I do that? Ok, done that.

Comment: Scanner has another constructor that takes an InputStream *and* and the charset name to use (as as String) : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String) - So just do this instead : Scanner cns = new Scanner(is,"UTF-8");

Comment: I'd rather use apache commons : `FileUtils.readFileToString(..)` or `FileUtils.readLines(..)`

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
File cityNamesFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("pl/shenlon/io/gui/appData/list.txt").toURI());
```

with

```
File cityNamesFile = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("pl/shenlon/io/gui/appData/list.txt").getFile());
```

Comment: only works in Eclipse for me, not in the jar run from the terminal

Comment: What classpath are you using from the command line? Eclipse handles that automatically for you.

Comment: I tried it setting no explicit classpath, I just run `java -jar xxx.jar`, from the terminal emulator, xxx.jar being a jar exported by Eclipse.

Comment: So then the file you are trying to load is in the JAR file under the path being specified? What type of error are you seeing?