# Converting a jar-file URI to a File

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I need to access a configuration file from within my Jar, so I use:

```
URL configUrl = Object.class.getResource("/config.xml");
```

Now I need to convert URL into a File object, because that's what the ConfigurationFile object downstream needs for initialization. When I try this:

```
new File(configUrl.toURI())
```

I get:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
```

When I try this:

```
 new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("config.xml").getFile())
```

I get:

```
File does not exist: 'file:\E:\Apps\jarfile.jar!\config.xml'
```

NOTE: Unfortunately I must have a File object, on an InputStream.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495069/error-error-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-uri-is-not-hierarchical-whil

Comment: Read this... The problem is, I must have a File object - the Configuration constructor will not accept an InputStream.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Then you are out of luck, unless you change the way you distribute the resource.

Comment: What is the API intended to consume/read the `config.xml`?  Is it intended for read only, or read/write?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: For me it's just a library class. I use it for read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file is inside of JAR... you can use getResourceAsStream() and read directly or using URL...

```
URL urlConfig = Object.class.getResource(CONFIG_FILE);
if (urlConfig == null) {
    // throw <error>
}
URLConnection connConfig = urlConfig.openConnection();
InputStream isConfig = connConfig.getInputStream(); // do things
```

Save content to a temporal File... (wait 1 second... mmm)

```
public static File doThing(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    File tmp = null;
    FileOutputStream tmpOs = null;
    try {
        tmp = File.createTempFile("xml", "tmp");
        tmpOs = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
        int len = -1;
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        while ((len = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            tmpOs.write(b, 0, len);
        }
    } finally {
        try { is.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        try { tmpOs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't make sense. A resource may be inside a JAR file, and an item in a JAR file simply is not a file, or a `File.`

Period.

If you need a `File` object you are going to have to distribute the item separately from the JAR file.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this:

```
File f;
try {
  f = new File(url.toURI());
} catch(URISyntaxException e) {
  f = new File(url.getPath());
}
```

Comment: That will only work if the resource really is a file. If it's in a JAR file, it isn't a file.

Comment: Yes, at the 3rd line (with toURI) I get the same error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical...         at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)"